# Calling REST Web services in Xamarin Forms in Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin.forms

I am new in Xamarin platform, I want to consume REST web services in xamarin forms using PCL. I also tried to use RestSharp library but didn't work. I also tried to use simple HttpWebRequest but not working.

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
        {
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
              //  Console.Out.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
                {

                        return "Response contained empty body...";
                  //  Console.Out.WriteLine("Response contained empty body...");
                }
                else
                {
                        return content;
                   // Console.Out.WriteLine("Response Body: \r\n {0}", content);
                }

                    return "";
                //Assert.NotNull(content);
            }

        }

        return "";
```

After running this code controller directly goes to

```
   private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

And pointer is on Debugger.Break();

Here is exception details

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled 
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

For RestSharp following is error occured.

[image]

If you have any best way to do it please share.

Comment: "but didn't work" and "but not working" don't give us any information about what you tried or what you observed. Please give more details.

Comment: @JonSkeet, If you have any suggestion for this problem.

Comment: Well for `WebRequest` you've clearly got an exception - but you haven't bothered to tell us what it was. That should be the first step. (Additionally, please stop adding a "signature" to your post.)

Comment: Sorry it is System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException. I don't know how it occur and how it is going to resolve.

Comment: So then you go into the TargetInvocationException and look at the InnerException property. It would have been a lot simpler if you'd just included a stack trace from the start...

Comment: I include exception detail in question. But I cover whole code with try catch block with TargetInvocationException, but it always got to Debugger.Break(); .

Comment: No, that isn't the exception detail. That's just the message. If you had the *complete* exception detail, that would include the stack trace and nested exceptions.

Comment: I cant find any stack trace, I am new to visual studio. I just see is call stack. When exception occur then in pop up box there is clipboard exception details and those details I mention in question.

Comment: Just calling `e.ExceptionObject.ToString()` should show you the details. It doesn't help that you've talked about having a try/catch block, but you haven't shown it...